# Telebot и скачать видео из telegram

Tags: python, telebot, видео, download

Для небольших задач по обработке изображения необходимо скачать видео из тг на тачку где крутится сам бот для дальнейшей обработки. Для написания бота взял всеми на хваленый telebot. Документация не помогла в поисках решения данного вопроса. Могу скачать что угодно но не видео. Подскажите пожалуйста как получить видео в той же директории что и для запуска бота. Привожу пример что я накопал в интернете но не могу получить `file_id` для видео.

```
 @bot.message_handler(content_types=['video'])      
 def send_text(message):

 bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты отправил мне видео')   
 file_info = bot.get_file(file_id)

 downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

  src = 'files/' + file_info.file_path
 with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
    new_file.write(downloaded_file)

bot.reply_to(message, "Пожалуй, я сохраню это")`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как Ответов мной не найдено прикладываю рабочую функцию которая скачивать видео от пользователя

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['video'])
def send_text(message):
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты отправил мне видео')
file_info = bot.get_file(message.video.file_id)

downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

src =  file_info.file_path
with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
    new_file.write(downloaded_file)

bot.reply_to(message, "Пожалуй, я сохраню это")
```